# Can I add "stars" pasta or very small soup shells pasta to boxed chicken broth & make in the microwave?

Tags: microwave, noodles, broth

I have boxed chicken broth I want to quickly make in the microwave and I want to add either tiny stars pasta, or "small soup shells" pasta. Both pastas are tiny, about 1/4 inch width & height. I don't have a stovetop available. How can I make everything in the microwave, preferably together/all at once? I would like a way to make about a quart at a time, including pasta, about 2-3 servings, maybe a quarter cup of pasta... I never made either of these pasta forms so don't know how big they will expand so I'm thinking a couple Tablespoons to a quarter cup dried pasta.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome! Is your goal to have a soup with pasta in it, or just end up with pasta with very little broth remaining?

Comment: My intention was to have a soup with more liquid volume than noodles, but when I talked to Chinese restaurants they put TEN wontons in a quart container of wonton soup. If you took out 5 wontons, the broth barely covers the remaining 5 wontons.

Answer (score 2):

i's put the pasta in regular water and microwave them for a couple of minutes; try 3, 4 minutes and adjust for doneness.

Once they are done, add them to the already heated up soup.

Comment: Is there a reason not to cook it in broth? That can help boost the flavor of the pasta, and also mean less cooking time overall.

Comment: I find it better to cook in the broth, then add back some water if it soaks up too much

Comment: Thanks @GloriaZ and everybody; I'm not sure of the proportions but I'll save the shells for a soup that has more ingrredients and try the stars first, maybe 3/4 cup to 2 cups of broth. I also intend to add rotisserie chicken, I have about half a quart bag of breast meat. I'll tear some up, maybe 1/2 cup per quart of soup? I'm not used to how things work here, I've made a couple other comments before I saw the @ directions...

Answer (score 1):

Great idea! And yes, I add chicken broth/stock to replace water in many things.  You may need additional seasoning, but just like the previous answer above, you just need to bring the liquid to a boil in the microwave, so 5-6 minutes should do it! I would leave the pasta to rest for a couple minutes extra to ensure it absorbed enough broth to become tender.